# How do I access Expo though cloudflared?

Tags: reactjs, windows, expo, native, cloudflare

I am trying to access my expo development server through cloudflared zero access server (ex. appdev.mydomain.com) so I can have multiple of my devs connect to their test devices without being on the same network. Expo puts its dev server on localhost for the web (127.0.0.1) and exposes the app dev server through exp://_****ip here****:8081. How do I setup cloudflared to expose it to a Url?

I tried to already make the config files in config.yml for cloudflared, but it keeps not connecting. My config file looks like this currently:

```
tunnel:<My tunnel id>
credentials-file: .\<My tunnel id>.json
ingress:
  - hostname: <my domain>
    service: tcp://127.0.0.1:8081
  - service: http_status:404  # Catch-all rule
```